# Redux - application state has the name of reducer as key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

Could someone please help me with this problem?
I've started to learn React and Redux but I'm stuck from a couple of days on configuring redux.

I'm assuming that when something triggers an action, redux through the reducers stack of functions should return an object that represents my application state.
Unfortunately, It returns an object with { reducerName => reducer result } basically means that if I've 4 reducers, the function store.getState() returns something like

```
{
 'reducerOne': entireApplicationState
 'reducerTwo': entireApplicationState
 'reducerThree': entireApplicationState
 'reducerFour': entireApplicationState
}
```

I'll really appreciate if someone can help me because I've finished all the ideas :)

This is my **application.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import HomePage from 'root_views/home';
import {store} from 'root_services/redux/store';

class Application extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <HomePage/>
            )
        }

}

var Provider = React.createClass({
        childContextTypes: {
            store: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
        },
        getChildContext: function () {
            return {store: this.props.store}
        },
        render: function () {
            return this.props.children;
        }
});


ReactDom.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Application/>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('application')
);
```

My **store.js**

```
    import { createStore } from 'redux';

    import {rootReducer} from './reducers/container';

    export const store = createStore(
        rootReducer,
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    );
```

My **container.js** that basically contains all my reducers

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

// This is just the action label
import {DATA_EXCHANGE_LOAD} from 'root_services/redux/actions/container'

const initialState = {
    data_exchange: {},
}

function dataExchange(state = {}, action) {

    switch (action.type) {

        case DATA_EXCHANGE_LOAD:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                data_exchange:{'reducerOne':'dataExchange'}
            });
            break;

        default:
            return initialState;
            break;

    }
};

function testReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case DATA_EXCHANGE_LOAD:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                data_exchange:{'reducerTwo':'testReducer'}
            });
            break;

        default:
            return initialState;
            break;
    }

};

// Export the combined reducers
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    dataExchange,
    testReducer
});
```

This is the action that triggers the event:

```
export function dataExchangeLoad(){
    return {
        type: DATA_EXCHANGE_LOAD,
    }
};
```

This is my component where the action is triggered:

```
import React from 'react'
import "../components/layouts/header/header.less";
import {dataExchangeLoad} from "root_services/redux/actions/container"

export default class HomePage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, {store}) {
        super(props);
        store.dispatch(dataExchangeLoad());
        console.log(store.getState());
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>test</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

HomePage.contextTypes = {
    store: React.PropTypes.object,
}
```

This is the result:

```
Object {dataExchange: Object, testReducer: Object}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but this is I believe exactly what the combineReducers() function does. Working as expected.

Comment: It looks weird to me, because in all the tutorials that I've seen, they have just one 'common' object, without the reducer name in the store state :(
Anyway, thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Blegh, tutorials. The perfect self-sabotage tools. Try the redux documentation instead: http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html .

Comment: Ok, now I'm feeling like a stupid...
Thank you so much for your time! :)

Comment: Yep, please also see the [Structuring Reducers - Using `combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html) docs page, which discusses common issues such as this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was already answered in comments `combineReducers` indeed works that way. In case you want to chain reducers so that action will go through all of them sequentially updating state in each one you can use [reduce-reducers](https://github.com/acdlite/reduce-reducers). Using this helper function it's possible to do something like that (looks like that is what you want to achieve):

```
import reduceReducers from 'reduce-reducers';

const reducer1 = (state = {}, action) => { 
  if (action.type === 'foo') {
    return ({ 
      ...state, 
      touchedBy: ['reducer1'],
    })
  }
  return state;
};

const reducer2 = (state = {}, action) => { 
  if (action.type === 'foo') {
    return ({ 
      ...state, 
      touchedBy: state.touchedBy.concat('reducer2'),
    })
  }
  return state;
};

const reducer = reduceReducers(reducer1, reducer2);

expect(reducer({}, { type: 'foo' }))
    .toMatchObject({ touchedBy: ['reducer1', 'reducer2'] });
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking, the link provided above in the comments is broken.  This link works and explains well how to rename the state coming from your reducers.  If you don't want to read, rename your reducer `import` or rename it inside your `combineReducer`.

Example1:
`import billReducer as billState from "./reducers";`

Example2:
`const rootReducer = combineReducer({billState: billReducer});`

[Using combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers)